# How to filter child collection by one of its attributes in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have a `Post` entity with a collection of `Comment` as shown below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "post"
)
private List<Comment> comments= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment entity

```
Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment{

@Id
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;

private boolean enabled;
```

I am using Spring Data JPA Repository `findById(Long id)` to fetch a `Post`. Currently, all `Comment` associated with that `Post` are returned. But the desired output is to fetch ony those `Comment` that has `enabled` attribute equal to `true`.

Is it possible to filter child collection in Spring Data JPA Repository?

I have tried the following

```
findByIdAndCommentsEnabledTrue(Long id);
findByIdAndCommentsEnabled(Long id, boolean enabled);
```

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the below JPA Query?

```
List<Post> findByCommentsEnabled(boolean enabled);
```

```
@Query("select post from Post post 
           fetch join post.comments comm
           where post.id = :postId and com.enabled = :enabled")
Post findPostWithCommentsEnables(@Param("postId") Long postId,@Param("enabled") boolean enabled);
```

Comment: I don't want to fetch `List<Post>`. It is a single `Post` entity whose `Comment` collection is filtered by `enabled` attribute.

Comment: then you can try with the native query example. try and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

A clean Hibernate based solution is to use ***@Where***. Below is the sample code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

@Id
private Long id;

@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "post"
)
@Where(clause = "enabled = true")
private List<Comment> comments= new ArrayList<>();
```